# How to check if Google Client_ID and Client_Secret Valid or not

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I am making a module in Node.js where the user can make their own Livestream Bot for youtube. The module requires the user to provide their client id and client secret of their application. But how do I check if the client id and client secret they entered is valid and if it isn't throw an appropriate error. Is there an endpoint to do that?

Comment: There's no endpoint checking for validity of client IDs and/or client secret. Sure thing these get validated internally within Google's back-end during each of steps of the OAuth authorization flow that require these to be given by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of validating the client id or the client secret.  The only way is to try them and if they dont work then display an error to the user.

You could maybe come up with a regex test for the client_id but i wouldn't recommend it as the format has changed several times over the years which would cause problems in your application.

I would just say try to use it if it fails give them an error message.

Note: I hope you are not prompting people to give you their client id and client secret as its against googles TOS for people to shire their client credentials if you are enc urging people to give you their credentials you are telling them to break the TOS.

Comment: The client Id and client secret wont be sent to me or sent to other online services it will be used to run api requests on that node process thats all

Answer (score 0):

Valid Code:

```
function ProjectValid($PostArray){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        ],
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query([
            'code'          => md5(time()),
            'client_id'     => $PostArray['ClientID'],
            'client_secret' => $PostArray['ClientSecret'],
            'redirect_uri'  => $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/'.$URL,
            'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code'
        ]),
    ));
    $Response   = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    if($Array=json_decode($Response,true) and isset($Array['error']) and $Array['error'] == 'invalid_grant'){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).